# Access database using Silverlight

Tags: database, silverlight

What's the best way (e.g. framework) to access a database using Silverlight?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using WCF RIA services. This allows you to access your Data using RIA Service Layer that can also have some business logic in it. For more details visit this article on RIA:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707344%28VS.91%29.aspx

Ragards.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is difficult to define "best". I think is more a personal preference. I have used a webservice and linq2Sql in the past.
I have used [this](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-2-Simple-Editing-of-Web-Service-Data-in-a-DataGrid.aspx) (http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-2-Simple-Editing-of-Web-Service-Data-in-a-DataGrid.aspx) tutorial as a base.