# Why do you need webservices to access a database from Silverlight?

Tags: .net, silverlight, web-services, data-access-layer

I am at the moment looking into several options to create a new app which can be accessed using the browser by multiple user in a closed intranet.

I thought about using Silverlight for its user-friendliness and its WPF design so close to the rich clients the future users are used to.

The project (of course) requires access to a database also within the intranet, hence I browsed the internet to see how data access was handled. I was surprised to see that you apparently *have* to use web services to interact with data, as mentioned in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591025/access-database-using-silverlight) which points [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707344%28VS.91%29.aspx) (one of many ways to use webservices).

Having already created various rich client within an intranet all interacting with database, I was surprised to be forced to use web services.

Indeed, I do understand the advantages of the web services; the security it provides, and all the other features of created a good DAL generally in software architecture. However, I can't see why you can't simply create (for example) a library containing the Linq to SQL classes and use this library as reference in the silverlight project to access data directly as you can do with classic rich client application. I understand that by doing that, you store the access data within the connection string of the app, but I can't see why it shouldn't work with a silverlight client.

**UPDATE**:

So, two questions:

1. Do we actually *have* to access data through web services?
2. If so, why is it different from the classic rich client approach?
3. Will Silverlight 5 enable me to do such thing?

Comment: I don't think having the client access the database directly is very desirable at all, you'd have to include database credentials in the client code, which is a security nightmare. In addition many of the data access method in the .net framework require additional drivers/clients to be installed, which would be another pain. What frameworks have you used to access the database directly from the client?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> However, I can't see why you can't simply create (for example) a library containing the Linq to SQL classes and use this library as reference in the silverlight project to access data directly as you can do with classic rich client application.

Silverlight, unlike WPF, doesn't use or have access to the full .NET Framework.  It's running under it's own, restricted CLR and framework.

In the decision of what to include and what to omit, it was decided that all of the data access components were left out of Silverlight.  This really makes it impossible to directly create the "library using SQL" as mentioned above.

By using WebServices (or WCF, which is really the preferred method), you are only required to be able to create and access the service references, which is supported in Silverlight.

Comment: I also saw that Silverlight 5 included a lot of new features added to the silverlight framework, do you know if data might be included?

Comment: @JSmaga: I don't believe it is.  It's not even in the .NET client profile, which is much, much larger than SL...  Using WCF services (or WCF RIA Services) really is the preferred way to go.  Silverlight is not intended to be used directly as a data consumer.

Comment: On from @Reed Copsey's great Answer,  also you have to realise that Silverlight has been designed to be a very "Thin" client type application framework, so you should be doing all your Database and Business Layer logic away from your UI. Or you would have larger XAP files to download on to the client machine. Yet again Great original post @Reed. +1

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight runs on the client workstation while the database resides on a server somewhere.  There would be all sorts of security issues of the party hosting the database had to make it accessable to client software directly.  Using a mechanism like web services hides the database away from client software.

As well, using web services as a data access method means that silverlight doesn't need to know how databases work so your data can be in a sql server, oracle, mysql or even flat files, and it makes no difference to the silverlight client.  It really is a smart way to do it.

Comment: He's using it internally on an intranet.  Security should be handled by AD/Kerberos so that wouldn't be an issue.  On the internet, web services make a lot of sense.  On an intranet, they make less sense, but still have value.

Comment: Still, abstracting away the database technology using a web service still applies.

Comment: I agree with the security issues, but as @Mystere Man said, I'm on intranet, so no problem here. Database abstraction is done by Linq To SQL I think, because I could create datacontext from SQL Server, SQL Compact, Excel, and I think more, so as long as I use the same interface, there is no problem either is it?